# TDD: Is it worth the effort to test the tests?

Tags: testing, tdd

I'm green when it comes to TDD so forgive me if this question sounds stupid.
So, TDD should prevent me from introducing bug/undefined behavior in my project. But what if I introduce this in my tests? Is it worth or even sane to test my tests or it's just a newbie concern?

I have scoured the internet but could not find anything on the matter. Only some articles about what TDD is in general.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Testing your tests is generally not necessary, but it is a good idea to make sure your tests are effective in actually testing your code. Here's some tips:

1. **Write clear, simple tests**: Keep tests small, focused, and easy to understand. Avoid complex logic and test only one behavior at a time.
2. **Use test doubles**: Utilize mocks, stubs, and fakes to isolate the behavior you're testing and minimize dependencies.
3. **Continuously review and refactor tests**: Periodically review your tests, update them as needed, and ensure they remain relevant as your code evolves.
   By following these practices, you can improve the quality of your tests and reduce the likelihood of introducing bugs in them, without needing to write tests for the tests themselves.
4. **Make sure your tests fail your builds**: Your tests should run before every build, and they should prevent you from building broken code. You can leverage "code coverage" to ensure that your tests actually cover meaningful portions of your code base.
5. **Favor integration tests over unit tests**: By using headless browsers and libraries such as Playwright or Puppeteer, integration tests can cover broad swaths of your app's behavior with very few lines of code. This is great because (a) your tests are less likely to change as your code changes and (b) you can ensure your code works properly when all the pieces are joined together, rather than in isolation.

Testing tests though? Don't worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

My 2013 article [Why trust tests?](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/04/02/why-trust-tests) covers that question. To summarise:

- Tests should be short, deterministic and have low complexity - preferably [cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) of 1 (although, once yet get better at it, you [may consider relaxing that rule under certain conditions](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2020/12/07/branching-tests)). Tests are code, and all code may have bugs, but bugs aren't evenly distributed. They tend to cluster where the code is complicated. Keeping tests simple helps reduce the risk of bugs in tests.
- In test-driven development, you [write the test first and *see it fail*.](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/10/21/a-red-green-refactor-checklist). Sometimes, to your surprise, it turns out that you've written a [tautological assertion](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/10/14/tautological-assertion). The red-green-refactor cycle catches such mistakes.

You can think of this process like double-entry bookkeeping. Seeing the test fail is feedback from the System Under Test (SUT) about the test. Seeing the test pass is information from the test about the SUT.

Answer (score 0):

TDD is not a synonym for software testing.

TDD is a specific way of doing software testing.

What will (/should/might) prevent you from introducing bug/undefined behavior in your project is ***software testing***, regardless of whether it is done the TDD way or not.

Although it is in theory conceivable to write tests for the tests, I have never heard of anyone being paranoid to such an extent as to actually do such a thing. It will probably be gruesome. Test functions are parameterless functions that return nothing, so you would first have to turn each one of them inside out in order to be able to test it.

And then of course comes the question of whether you should write tests for the tests of the tests.  It is a rhetorical question, you don't need to answer it.

You don't need to go there. Don't go there.

Answer (score 0):

The transition from red to green demonstrates that the test code is responding to changes in the production code. It *is* the test of the test.

TDD gives us confidence about this connection. If you ever feel doubt about a test, break the production code on purpose to see if the test prevents that failing change. See [Who Tests the Tests? How to Increase Confidence in Your Tests](https://qualitycoding.org/who-tests-the-tests/)